# Eval Error in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am getting the eval error shown below, but everything in my program is in working order so am wondering why I am getting this? There is no indication of where the problem is located from the stack trace. `isChecked(field, value)` is a function which returns a boolean which I'm evaluating in the `ng-model` attribute of about 70 checkboxes generated with `ng-repeat`. Any help and advice on if this is an issue, would be much appreciated :)

```
Eval Error: Cannot assign to isChecked(field, val) while evaling [isChecked(field, val)]

FROM:
#0      Expression.assign (package:angular/core/parser/syntax.dart:45:7)
#1      _UnwrapExceptionDecorator.assign (package:angular/core/parser/parser.dart:125:26)
#2      BoundExpression.assign (package:angular/core/parser/syntax.dart:60:41)
#3      NgModel.modelValue= (package:angular/directive/ng_model.dart:211:11)
#4      NgModel.viewValue= (package:angular/directive/ng_model.dart:200:5)
#5      InputCheckbox.InputCheckbox.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/directive/ng_model.dart:318:19)
#6      NgModelOptions._runFuncDebounced (package:angular/directive/ng_model_options.dart:80:11)
#7      NgModelOptions.executeChangeFunc (package:angular/directive/ng_model_options.dart:68:20)
#8      InputCheckbox.InputCheckbox.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/directive/ng_model.dart:317:49)
#9      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:915)
#10     _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:510)
#11     VmTurnZone._onRunUnary.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:55)
#12     VmTurnZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:104:16)
#13     VmTurnZone._onRunUnary (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:7)
#14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:811)
#15     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:717)
#16     _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:743)


STACKTRACE:
#0      _UnwrapExceptionDecorator.assign (package:angular/core/parser/parser.dart:127:7)
#1      BoundExpression.assign (package:angular/core/parser/syntax.dart:60:41)
#2      NgModel.modelValue= (package:angular/directive/ng_model.dart:211:11)
#3      NgModel.viewValue= (package:angular/directive/ng_model.dart:200:5)
#4      InputCheckbox.InputCheckbox.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/directive/ng_model.dart:318:19)
#5      NgModelOptions._runFuncDebounced (package:angular/directive/ng_model_options.dart:80:11)
#6      NgModelOptions.executeChangeFunc (package:angular/directive/ng_model_options.dart:68:20)
#7      InputCheckbox.InputCheckbox.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/directive/ng_model.dart:317:49)
#8      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:915)
#9      _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:510)
#10     VmTurnZone._onRunUnary.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:55)
#11     VmTurnZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:104:16)
#12     VmTurnZone._onRunUnary (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:7)
#13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:811)
#14     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:717)
#15     _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:743)
```

HTML of checkboxes:

```
  <fieldset ng-repeat="field in $.filterFields">
      <legend>Filter by {{field}}</legend>
      <span ng-repeat="val in $.getValuesForField(field)">
          <label>{{val}}</label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="$.checkboxClicked(field, val)" ng-model="isChecked(field, val)">
      </span>
  </fieldset>
```

Source code of isChecked:

```
bool isChecked(String key, String value){
    if(alertFilter.containsKey(key) && alertFilter[key].contains(value)) {
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
}
```

P.S. 'alertFilter' here is obtained from a service. The error fires when alertFilter is updated - which triggers 4 other parts of the program which share this filter, to update. Note that these other parts do not update alertFilter, they only read from it.

Comment: Could you please add some code (`isChecked()` and the html of the checkbox)?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the response. I have updated the OP with extra code. The alertFilter variable in isChecked is obtained via a getter which gets it from a service, as multiple parts of the program share this filter. I'm assuming the error has something to do with this but I am still confused as to why there is nothing wrong with my program despite the error.

Comment: I think the added code demonstrates well what you're doing, but I have no idea why it's failing.